# C++ variables in class inheritance not working

Tags: c++

Can somebody explain, why:

a->b.edge = 10;

is not working and returning error:

error: ‘class Colider’ has no member named ‘b’

Is it because when i have pointer on Colider, i can't use it to point on Colider_Triange class?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
} position;

class Colider
{
    public:
        unsigned int type;
};

class Colider_Triangle: public Colider
{
public:
    position edge1;
    position edge2;
    position edge3;
};

Colider_Triangle::Colider_Triangle()
{
    edge1.x = 1;
}

class Colider_Sphear: public Colider
{
    public:
    position pos;
    unsigned int r;
};

int main(){

    Colider* a;
    a = new Colider_Triangle;
    a->b.edge = 10;
    delete(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you expect `b` to represent. There is nothing named `b` in the code you've shown.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Implement 1 thing at a time. Incremental development makes it easier to see errors fast. When you write or possibly copy paste many things at once, chances of success at first compile drops.

Comment: Do not use `typedef struct` in C++

Comment: "Is it because when i have pointer on Colider, i can't use it to point on Colider_Triange class?" no you cannot use pointer to `Colider` as pointer to `Colider_Triange` directly and no error is not because of that, but because you do not have `b` anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can somebody explain, why:
>
> ```
> a->b.edge = 10;
> ```
>
> is not working and returning error:
>
> ```
> error: ‘class Colider’ has no member named ‘b’
> ```

The explanation is simple:

1. `a` is a pointer to the type `Colider`.
2. `Colider` has no member named `b`.
3. You've written the sub expression `a->b` which can only work if `Colider` has a member named `b`.
4. 2. and 3. are in conflict.

> Is it because when i have pointer on Colider, i can't use it to point on Colider_Triange class?

No. You *can* point to an object of derived type using a pointer to a base type.

---

> ```
> delete(a);
> ```

This is another bug: The behaviour of deleting an object through a pointer to base class is undefined unless the destructor of the base class is declared `virtual`.

Comment: I applaud the effort, but what's the point of answering questions that make no sense to begin with? Who will this help in the future?

Comment: @Rotem I'm sure that there are enough beginning programmers that eventually someone will encounter a similar problem.

Comment: @user2079303 Certainly, but how would they ever find this question/answer?

Comment: @MaxLanghof "has no member named" is an error that's within the content of this page, and therefore might lead a user here through search. Unfortunately, the title is not very accurate. This is one of SO's weaknesses: The author of the question is control of the title, while quite often the asker themselves don't understand the context sufficiently to be able to write an accurate tittle.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because when i have pointer on Colider, i can't use it to point
>   on Colider_Triange class?

You can use Colider* to point to Colider_Triangle instance, but you can use only Colider interface then.